# Angular 2/4 Animation on div height

Tags: angular, animation

I'll try to keep it short.
For some reason, My animation seems to work fine on width/opacity style attribute yet it doesn't work on height attribute....

the animation  -

```js
trigger('Grow', [
transition(':enter', [   // :enter is alias to 'void => *'
  style({height:'0'}),
  animate(500, style({height:'*'})) 
]),
transition(':leave', [   // :leave is alias to '* => void'
  animate(500, style({height:0})) 
])
])
```

Changing the 'height' to width/opacity and the animation works great...
any one knows wheres the issue? couldn't find relative answer anywhere .

an example of what I'm trying to achieve is like the animation in udemy, upon clicking on a section the div height expands the display all the videos - 
https://www.udemy.com/meteor-react/

thanks for reading .

**Update** - still doesn't work...

maybe its something with what I'm animating on?

```xml
<div class="animate" *ngIf="show" [@animate]> 
  <div  *ngFor="let video of section"><a>hi</a></div>
</div>
```

what happens is once I click, the div.animate is showing (by ngif) and fills with lots of lines that says 'hi'.
I want that on div.animate show, to make the animation I specified.

help! ^^

Comment: I see... well if thats the case you have any idea how udemy does this animation on the example I attached

Comment: Do something like [@animate]="myAnimationState". Idk when you need it to show, but in my example it toggles my 'helpMenuOpen' variable from 'out' state to 'in' state on (click) event. You need to control that 'myAnimationState' variable to your desired effect to change from ':enter' to ':leave', as you've named it. For example, maybe you want on route change; so listen to route changes to change that variable.

Comment: Ok, eventually I just took off the ngIf and set it to hidden in-order to animate correctly... its fine as there isn't too much content under that div to cause a problem.

thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Animations absolutely do work on an `ngIf` change, you just have to set up your animation to handle this.  Set the states as `'*'` and `'void'` instead of `'in'` and `'out'`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You don't have any states defined in your `trigger()` function.

[trigger](https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger) creates a named animation trigger, containing a list of `state()` and `transition()` entries to be evaluated when the expression bound to the trigger changes (the expression being `[@slideInOut]="helpMenu"` in example below).

```js
@Component({
  ...
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('in', style({
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: '*',
        width: '300px'
      })),
      state('out', style({
        opacity: '0',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        height: '0px',
        width: '0px'
      })),
      transition('in => out', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
      transition('out => in', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

  helpMenu: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.helpMenu = 'out';
  }

  toggleHelpMenu(): void {
    this.helpMenu = this.helpMenu === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
  }

}
```

Then use it in your view like this:

```xml
<div [@slideInOut]="helpMenu">
   <h1>My Title</h1>
   <p>My paragraph</p>
</div>
<button (click)="toggleHelpMenu()">help</button>
```

Comment: By doing that you get the same animation as in Udemy?
 If you can edit and add the rest of your code on how you implement it and change the state that would be great! thanks

Comment: @Ben Check updated answer, but no I don't have access to udemy, this is just an example of an animation that changes height and width

Comment: I found that when the target height was set to 'auto' the animation jumped, whereas when the height property was set to '*' the animation was smooth.

Comment: Instead of having 2 `transition(...)`'s you could just have a single one that works for both by doing: `transition('* => *', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))`

Comment: This does not work with `enter` and `leave`!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Angular animations cat work with `*ngIf` directive perfectly fine.

Right now there's a [section](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#use-of-ngif-and-ngfor-with-enter-and-leave) in the official docs that describes how to do it.

The problem in your example is that template animation trigger is specified as `[@animate]`,
but in component's animations declaration actual trigger is `Grow`. Thus, template trigger needs to be specified as `[@Grow]`.

app.component.ts

```ts
    trigger("grow", [ // Note the trigger name
      transition(":enter", [
        // :enter is alias to 'void => *'
        style({ height: "0", overflow: "hidden" }),
        animate(500, style({ height: "*" }))
      ]),
      transition(":leave", [
        // :leave is alias to '* => void'
        animate(500, style({ height: 0, overflow: "hidden" }))
      ])
    ])
```

app.component.html

```html
<div class="test" *ngIf="show" [@grow]> <!-- Use exact same trigger name here -->
  <div *ngFor="let video of section"><a>hi</a></div>
</div>
```

Working demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animations-stackoverflow-43497431?file=src/app/app.component.html)